# Running Applescript from a Cocoa application

Tags: cocoa, applescript

I want to run a simple applescript in a cocoa application. I read the apple documentation on the matter but it was too confusing for me (a beginner) to understand.

```
tell application "iTunes" to play
```

Comment: nope. I could not get anything out of apples documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ScriptableCocoaApplications/SApps_script_classes/SAppsScriptClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000034-BBCBGCEI), you use the [NSAppleScript](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAppleScript_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class.

The very short API reference has a section called "Initializing a Script," one method of which is `-initWithSource:`, which takes an NSString. You'll create your object this way.

Once you have your script object, you can then either `-compileAndReturnError:` then `-executeAndReturnError:` as separate steps, or just `-executeAndReturnError:`, which - according to the documentation for that method - tries to compile the source first if it's not been already, then executes.

So, in theory, you could probably do all this in one line. (alloc, init..., autorelease, executeAndReturnError:) if you ignore errors like a naughty developer.

Note the warning that NSAppleScript can only be executed from the main thread (ie, not from an NSOperation/Queue or other threads).

---

Comment: so heres my script object/code.
NSAppleScript *ascript = [[NSAppleScript alloc]init];
[ascript executeAndReturnError:]

how do i tell it what my script is

Comment: i dont see what im doing wrong. i dont know how to fill the argument after executeAndReturnError:

this is literally my third day of objective c.

Comment: Hint: "-init" vs. "-initWithSource:".

As for "filling in the argument," see: http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/Learning_Objective-C_A_Primer/ and http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/OOP_ObjC/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: OK i've came up with this. But it doesn't seem to run the script because it doesnt play or pause my itunes.
-(IBAction)playpause:(id)sender{
 NSAppleScript *playScript;
 playScript = [[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithSource:@"iTunesPlayPause.scpt"];
 [playScript executeAndReturnError:nil];
}

Comment: WHOOOOOOOOO!! i got it!!!!! initWithSource:@"" i should have put the applescript raw code. man i feel so accomplished.

Comment: @shorty876: the parameter of the method is not the name of the file containing the source code, but the string containing the code.